# Updating a field in a changed row collection does not update underlying table in C#

Tags: c#, database

I have a dataset with table in, and basically  I call

```
DataTable aTable = dataSet.Tables["DocData"].GetChanges();
foreach (DataRow aRow in aTable.Rows)
{
    switch (aRow.RowState)
    {
        case DataRowState.Unchanged:
            break;
        case DataRowState.Added:
           aRow["ID"] = getNewID();
           //...updates database here
           aRow.AcceptChanges();
           break;
     }
}
```

Now the change to the `ID` on the changed row is not updated in the underlying table object the changed row came from... how can I make this happen? I need to add the `id` when a new row is saved.

Comment: If I check the rows from the table then I can edit those its the changed rows returned by GetChanges.  But ts inefficient to iterate all the rows of the table.

Comment: I realize that Accept changes does not change my database I am doing that but I want to change the dataTable object rows from the changed rows array returned by GetChanges and have them reflected in that DataTable object.  So it reflects what I have just written to the database from the changed row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `GetChanges` loops over your rows to retrieve every changed row and builds a copy of that rows. Thus your update changes the copy not the original rows.

It seems that you couldn't avoid to have a loop somewhere to retrieve the added rows so, you could try with this simpler code, thanks to Linq.

```
foreach (DataRow aRow in aTable.AsEnumerable()
                               .Where(x => x.RowState == DataRowState.Added)
{
     aRow["ID"] = getNewID();
}
```